# Hookstate global state array type intellisense not corectly identifying

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Here's a component with a local and global state of the same type:

```
import { createState, useState } from "@hookstate/core";

const storeWarnings = createState<
  { type: "warning" | "danger"; msg: string }[]
>([]);

export const Warnings = () => {
  const warnings = useState(storeWarnings);

  const warningsLocal = useState<{ type: "warning" | "danger"; msg: string }[]>(
    []
  );

  return (
    <div
      style={{ position: "fixed", top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, zIndex: 1 }}
      onClick={() => {
        warnings.set((prev) => [
          ...prev,
          { type: "danger", msg: "click test" },
        ]);
        warningsLocal.set((prev) => [
          ...prev,
          { type: "danger", msg: "click test" },
        ]);
      }}
    >
      {warnings.value.map((warn) => (
        <span key={warn.msg}>{warn.msg}</span>
      ))}

      {warningsLocal.value.map((warn) => (
        <span key={warn.msg}>{warn.msg}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The type for the local state is:

```
const warningsLocal: State<{
    type: "warning" | "danger";
    msg: string;
}[]>
```

The type for the global state is:

```
const warnings: State<readonly {
    type: "warning" | "danger";
    msg: string;
}[] | Record<number, {
    type: "warning" | "danger";
    msg: string;
}>>
```

And since it is not identifying as an array the `.map` method and the `prev` inside `.set` it's not identifying correctly.

Comment: what's the issue again? can you create a codesandbox perhaps?

Comment: The issue is the last sentence, the state is as array but intellisence is saying it also some other stuff. I'll see if codesandbox also has the same behavior